# Is takeEvery blocking in redux saga?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I've always assumed that `takeEvery` (or `takeLatest` etc.) is blocking and will live as long as its parent lives due to it using a `while(true)` in its implementation (or basic implementation).

However, i've put a basic example together that demonstrates the saga running to the `finally` block immediately after calling `takeEvery`.

```js
import { call, takeEvery } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* handleTest(data: any) {
  yield call([console, console.log], data);
}

export function* rootSaga() {
  try {
    yield takeEvery("test", handleTest);
  } finally {
    console.log("end");
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/pusher-transcriptions-ff7qz?file=/src/rootSaga.ts:0-259

Answer (score 1):

According to the official docs it is not blocking https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#blocking--non-blocking